# Cannot edit JTextField - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Was just experimenting trying to build a simple application in Java swing. Whenever i attempt to use the GUI builder which generates the code for you, I seem to not be able to edit the text field when the program is running. I have set the field to editable yet I still encounter problems. Code is below:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CarRentalGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public CarRentalGUI() {
    initComponents(); 
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(230,230,230)); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new JTextField("Text Here", 10);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("CarRental");
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
    setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    setName("frame"); // NOI18N

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Volkswagen Golf", "Ford Fiesta", "Citroen C2", "Vauxhall Insignia", "Peugeot Bipper" }));
    jComboBox2.setName(""); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setText("Select Car:");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");
    jLabel1.setName(""); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setText("Duration: ");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14" }));

    jRadioButton1.setText("NUS Student Card");

    jRadioButton2.setText("Employee");

    jLabel3.setText("Discount Code:");

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(548, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(119, 119, 119)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
            .addGap(71, 71, 71)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(124, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jTextField1.setEditable(true);

    getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CarRentalGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CarRentalGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CarRentalGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CarRentalGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    Connection conn;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/car_rental";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "password";

    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        System.out.print("Connected Successfully\n");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.print(ex.toString());
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CarRentalGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

I would try and attempt to hand write the Java swing elements in the code but i have little java experience and wouldn't know how to edit the layout. Is there a reason why I am unable to edit the field "JTextField1" ?

Thanks,

Aces

Comment: Remove `setFocusableWindowState(false);`, this is prevent in frame from been able to receive keyboard focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `setFocusableWindowState(false);`, this is prevent the frame from been able to receive keyboard focus

From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setFocusableWindowState-boolean-)

> Sets whether this `Window` can become the focused `Window` if it meets the
>   other requirements outlined in `isFocusableWindow`. If this `Window`'s
>   focusable `Window` state is set to `false`, then `isFocusableWindow` will
>   return `false`. If this `Window`'s focusable `Window` state is set to `true`,
>   then `isFocusableWindow` may return true or false depending upon the
>   other requirements which must be met in order for a `Window` to be
>   focusable. 
> Setting a `Window`'s focusability state to `false` is the
>   standard mechanism for an application to identify to the AWT a `Window`
>   which will be used as a floating palette or toolbar, and thus should
>   be a non-focusable `Window`. Setting the focusability state on a visible
>   Window can have a delayed effect on some platforms — the actual change
>   may happen only when the Window becomes hidden and then visible again.
>   To ensure consistent behavior across platforms, set the Window's
>   focusable state when the `Window` is invisible and then show it.

And [isFocusableWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow--)

> Returns whether this `Window` can become the focused `Window`, that is, whether this `Window` or any of its subcomponents can become the focus owner. For a `Frame` or `Dialog` to be focusable, its focusable `Window` state must be set to `true`. For a `Window` which is not a `Frame` or `Dialog` to be focusable, its focusable Window state must be set to `true`, its nearest owning `Frame` or `Dialog` must be showing on the screen, and it must contain at least one `Component` in its focus traversal cycle. If any of these conditions is not met, then neither this `Window` nor any of its subcomponents can become the focus owner.